# How do I set names.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I want to know how to set x names in a option variable.

`var names = {};`

and then set `names.{username from event (e.user.username)} = 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to pass variable as key.

```js
var username = 'Lorem';
var names = {};

names[username] = 1;
console.log(names)
```